# How to open a specific screen with quick_actions official plugin in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub

I implemented the [Quick_actions](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quick_actions) plugin in my project and i want to open a specific screen but in the quickaction handler function the navigator doesnt work. whit a `Try-Catch`, the exception shows that the context showld be from a navigator, but im using the context of the navigatorKey of my MaterialApp.

if i put any other function like a `print('some text')` it works, the problem only happend when I try to use the navigator

Create the quick actions and add the handler function

```dart
createQuickActions() {
    quickActions.initialize(
      (String shortcutId) {
        switch (shortcutId) {
          case 'settings':
            try {
              Navigator.push(
                MyApp.navigatorKey.currentContext,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => SettingsScreen(sistemas),
                ),
              );
            } catch (e) {
              print(e);
            }
            print('selected: $shortcutId');
          break;
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Initialice the quick actions

```dart
 quickActions.setShortcutItems(
      <ShortcutItem>[
        const ShortcutItem(
          type: 'settings',
          localizedTitle: 'settings',
          icon: 'settings',
        ),
     ],
   );
```

All this code its in my `SplashScreen` because the plugin's documentation says that should be in an early state of the app

I expect that the app open the `settings screen` and `print 'settings'` but it opens the `main screen` and `print 'settings'` if the app its already open, but if its not it tries to open something and then close itself (not `force close` message)

Answer (score 5):

In the following example, 
Use MainView in quick action will open Login widget and directly click app will open Home widget

You can reference https://www.filledstacks.com/snippet/managing-quick-actions-in-flutter/ for detail

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quick_actions/quick_actions.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class QuickActionsManager extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  QuickActionsManager({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  _QuickActionsManagerState createState() => _QuickActionsManagerState();
}

class _QuickActionsManagerState extends State<QuickActionsManager> {
  final QuickActions quickActions = QuickActions();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _setupQuickActions();
    _handleQuickActions();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }

  void _setupQuickActions() {
    quickActions.setShortcutItems(<ShortcutItem>[
      ShortcutItem(
          type: 'action_main',
          localizedTitle: 'Main view',
          icon: Platform.isAndroid ? 'quick_box' : 'QuickBox'),
      ShortcutItem(
          type: 'action_help',
          localizedTitle: 'Help',
          icon: Platform.isAndroid ? 'quick_heart' : 'QuickHeart')
    ]);
  }

  void _handleQuickActions() {
    quickActions.initialize((shortcutType) {
      if (shortcutType == 'action_main') {
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()));
      } else if(shortcutType == 'action_help') {
        print('Show the help dialog!');
      }
    });
  }

}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'QuickActions Demo', home: QuickActionsManager(child: Home()));
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text('Home')));
  }
}

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  const Login({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text('Login')));
  }
}
```

[image]